# Log file is not getting populated in rcp app through command prompt

Tags: windows, eclipse-rcp, command-prompt, rcp

I am using the command to launch my RCP application.

```
MyApplication.exe -debug .options -console -noExit >> log.txt
```

I can see the login screen and I want to write all the console output into a log file. Its creating the log file but it is not populating or writing anything to it. Am I missing something?

Comment: `-consoleLog` not `-console`

Comment: @greg-449 still not writing to log file.